# How do I change the font size of TextView through a button?

Tags: java, button, text-size

I'm making a calculator app and I am trying to make it so that the CA (clear all) button resets the size of the text shown in the input and output spaces. Because I set the text in the input and output spaces to autosize depending on the length of the equation and answer, the font size stays decreased on my next input and output as well. Is there a way to make the button revert the text back to it's original size?

TextView for input

```
<TextView
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/input"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
            android:autoSizePresetSizes="@array/text_sizes"
            android:maxLength="10"
            android:background="@color/black"
            android:fontFamily="@font/lgc"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="30sp" />
```

Comment: I'm using android studio

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setTextSize(unit, size)` under button click event:

```
yourTextViewID.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 18f);
```

Refer [Doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView)

Comment: It doesn't seem to work even after I put in original values for the size

Comment: btnClear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                input.setText("");
                output.setText("");
                input.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 30);
                output.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 70);
            }
        });

Comment: TextView mytextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yourTextViewID);
mytextView .setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 18f);

Comment: The fontsize still stay decreased, I included the code for the TextView in my main post.